# How can I get a resource string without fallback to the default culture

Tags: c#, .net, internationalization, resx, resourcemanager

I have the following setup in my app:

```
MyResources.resx // english strings
MyResources.zh-CN.resx // chinese strings
```

Due to lag in the translation process, some keys have english values but no chinese values. In other cases, the entire zh-CN resx file does not exist. By default, `ResourceManager` will fall back to the english value if the chinese value does not exist. This is acceptable for my use-case in most scenarios. However, I currently have a need to fetch a chinese resource string WITHOUT fallback to english.

My question is: what is the right way to do this?

I had initially thought that this could be done via the GetResourceSet method:

```
var manager = MyResources.ResourceManager;

var set = manager.GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("zh-CN"), createIfNotExists: true, tryParents: false);
if (set == null || set.GetString("key") == null) { /* not translated! */ }

// however, this has issues because resource set lookup is cached:

// this will force the association of the zh-CN culture with the
// English resource set unde the hood
manager.GetString("key", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("zh-CN"));

// now this returns the English resource set, thus breaking my check
var set2 = manager.GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("zh-CN"), createIfNotExists: true, tryParents: false);
if (set == null || set.GetString("key") == null) { /* checks whether key exists in english :-( */ }
```

Comment: Add values to to the zh-CN resource file

Comment: @Fabio presumably you are suggesting some kind of stub values? I don't disagree that this is ideal; however the code in question is a library that is used by ~30 different codebases managed by different developers. I'd like to have a solution that doesn't rely on them all instantly updating their codebases with empty resx files whenever we start translating our resources into a new language.

Comment: How localizations strings are accessed in the code? By generated classes (Visual Studio will generate resources classes) `ResourceNamespace.MyResourcesFileName.KeyofString` or by using ResourceManager with hardcoded key: `ResourceManager.GetString("KeyofString")`?

Comment: @downvoter why the downvote?

Answer (score 3):

That's a one-off scenario since the intent is always to provide a fallback. But you could still work around it, something like this (slightly simplistic example). This only returns what the `ResourceManager` provides for its given culture if it's different from the default.

I just put some things in the constructor out of habit/convention. You could move the `ResourceManager`, desired `CultureInfo`, or both to method arguments.

```
public class NonFallbackResourceManager
{
    private readonly CultureInfo _desiredCulture;
    private readonly ResourceManager _resourceManager;

    public NonFallbackResourceManager(CultureInfo desiredCulture, ResourceManager resourceManager)
    {
        _desiredCulture = desiredCulture;
        _resourceManager = resourceManager;
    }

    public string GetString(string key)
    {
        var desiredCultureString = _resourceManager.GetString(key, _desiredCulture);
        var defaultCultureString = _resourceManager.GetString(key, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        return string.Equals(desiredCultureString, defaultCultureString) 
            ? String.Empty 
            : desiredCultureString;
    }
}
```

It does not account for scenarios where there may be multiple levels of fallback.